# Python: Multihreading downloader blocking each other

Tags: python, multithreading

I have an infinite multithreaded downloader, which works like this:

```
queue = Queue()  # links for downloading

def downloader(queue):
    while:
        link = queue.get()
        # do download with requests library

for i in range(4):
    task = Thread(target=downloader, args=(queue,))
    task.start()
```

Queue is periodically filled with new data. But when I print out which link was downloaded, it looks like threads are not working in parallel, for example:

```
time 0 - thread 1 - link 1
time 1 - thread 1 - link 2
time 2 - thread 1 - link 3
time 3 - thread 1 - link 4
time 4 - thread 2 - link 5
time 5 - thread 2 - link 6
time 6 - thread 2 - link 7
time 7 - thread 3 - link 8
time 8 - thread 3 - link 9
time 9 - thread 3 - link 10
time 10 - thread 1 - link 11
time 11 - thread 1 - link 12
```

I hoped that it will be more like: thread 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4. Server has 4 cpus.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the requests code?

Comment: How do you measure your `time`? With what frequency do you insert the links in the `queue`? How much time does `downloader` take to complete? (Is it possible that each execution of `downloader` completes _before_ the next link is inserted in the `queue`?) Also note that multithreading does not necessarily use all CPUs. You also have multithreading on a single CPU.

Comment: In short:
`session = requests.Session()`
`session.cookies = login_cookies.copy()`
`for link in links:`
`data = session.get(url, params={...})`
`if data.status_code == 200:`
`fp = open(filepath, 'wb')`
`fp.write(data.content)`
`fp.close()`

Comment: @a_guest: Time is measured by `datetime.datetime.now()`. Queue is filled ones and then filled when count of items in queue is lower then 200. It downloads small files (1-2kB) so one file is downloaded in 1 (or less) second. I think it is not problem of cpu, because this script uses all cpus up to 5%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check your output file(s) and where each thread is writing.  Write locks could be causing the code to execute more serially than expected.

Comment: Good point, I would also create a separate queue for the `content`s and move the file operations to a separate thread.

Comment: @a_guest: Not a bad idea, I will try it :)